# Datasheet says EEPROM address is 0xA0 but it worked for me on 0x50. Is there a particular reason to right-shift bits?

Tags: bit-manipulation, memory-address, i2c, eeprom, zynq

I read the device data of the SFP Optical Transceiver module using it's EEPROM. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD1Xd.png) image shows that the EEPROM's address is 0xA0, but it didn't work for me. It worked when I entered the address as 0x50.

0x50 is a right-shifted version of 0xA0. Is there a particular reason to right-shift bits?

Links

- [AN2030(containing the EEPROM address)](http://sup.xenya.si/sup/info/finisar/an-2030-finisar.pdf)

Comment: Can you verify that the SDA line follows the byte sent by your i2c interface? (using a scope or logic analyzer)

Comment: 0xA0 is the left-shifted version of the address (the bottom bit is the direction bit and is not part of the address), 0x50 is in some sense the actual address. Which one you need depends on what you do with it

Comment: @harold yes, you're right. But it isn't written in the documentation that the LSB is the direction bit. However, I believe this is the most relevant explanations for the problem. Thanks

Comment: Many vendors of I2C devices put it wrongly (meaning they are using **read** and **write** 8-bit addresses).